# Where can get more information about the Java OpenStreetMap API?

Tags: java, api, mapping

I'm planning to develop an application that will get GPS data and show the user some other things on a map. I don't want to use Google Maps for some reasons. I searched and found the Java OpenStreetMap Editor (JOSM).

I couldn't find any good programming tutorials that use the JOSM API. Anybody know a good site for programming tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some helpful links:

1. [JOSM Webpage](http://josm.openstreetmap.de/)
2. [JOSM Wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JOSM)
3. [JOSM Guide](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JOSM/Guide)
4. [JOSM Help](http://josm.openstreetmap.de/wiki/Help)
5. [JOSM Tutorial Videos](http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/series?name=mS2P1ZqS6)

That should get you started. Hope it helps -